# Enabling synchronization in consumer and provider ldap

Tags: linux, redhat, ldap, openldap

I am completely new to ldap (openldap in this case). My boss gave me the task of creating a second ldap server, and copying the data from the existing ldap server to the new one I created.

I was able to accomplish this by reading documentation and doing a lot of google. In any case, for the new ldap server I copied the slapd.conf file from the existing ldap server, and ran 'slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d' This created the cn=config.

My boss tested the environment. It works fine, but now he's asking me to do a one way synchronization from the existing ldap server to the new one that was just created.

Again after reading documentation, and doing a lot of google, I think I finally know what needs to be done.

This new ldap server is not being used, and I don't really know how to use ldapmodify or any ldap client tools for that matter, to add the parameters below. I am actually planning to delete the contents on the slapd.d directory, update the slapd.conf file with the new parameters, and re-run 'slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d' to recreate the cn=config with the new parameters. I know it's not the best way to do it, but it should work.

--sync consumer

syncrepl

rid=123

type=RefreshandPersist

provider=ldaps://ldap-master.example.com:389

bindmethod=simple

searchbase="dc=example,dc=com"

retry="10 6 60 +"

attrs="cn,sn,displayName,givenName,mail,uid"

binddn="cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com"

credentials={SSHA}password

Now, this method of updating the cn=config won't work for the changes that need to be made on the replica provider to enable the synchronization.

As far as I know, I only need to add one line:

overlay syncprov

My question is how do I add this line to the cn=config on the existing and working ldap server? I obviously can't recreate the configuration using slaptest.

Your help and suggestions are greatly appreciated

-V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you need to get familiar with using `ldapmodify`, the man-page for it has examples which show how to make changes.

Without knowing how your LDAP server is configured, I can't give you a simple "do this" answer. However, you need to do something similar to the following:

```
# ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
^D
```

This is the `cn=config` equivalent of having `overlay syncprov` in the `slapd.conf` file. But I'm assuming you a) only have the one LDAP database backend configured, b) You're using the HDB backend, c) LDAPI connections are allowed. This also doesn't configure a user to be used for connecting from the new LDAP server, nor set up any ACL's to allow it to read everything, etc.

I would encourage you to read the OpenLDAP documentation, particularly http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html which covers setting up replication.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work. I did do more reading to figure out what to do, but your example was pretty much what I end up doing, the only difference is that I put the parameters on an ldif file. ldapmodify -a -x -H "ldaps://localhost:636" -D "cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=example,dc=com" -W -f  overlay.ldif